# Basic questions about Reactor signals

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have some questions regarding the output of the following code:

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d")
        .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line: 18
        .flatMap(value ->
                Mono.just(value.toUpperCase()).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()), 2)
        .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line: 21
        .take(3)
        .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line: 23
        .subscribe(x -> 
             System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                               " , " + x));

Thread.sleep(1000 * 1000);
```

Output:

```
1. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)    Flux.log(App.java:18)
2. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.FlatMapMain)     Flux.log(App.java:21)
3. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - onSubscribe(FluxTake.TakeSubscriber)     Flux.log(App.java:23)
4. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - request(unbounded)   Flux.log(App.java:23)
5. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - request(unbounded)   Flux.log(App.java:21)
6. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - | request(2)     Flux.log(App.java:18)
7. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - | onNext(a)  Flux.log(App.java:18)
8. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - | onNext(b)  Flux.log(App.java:18)
9. 11:29:11 [elastic-2] INFO  - onNext(A)   Flux.log(App.java:21)
10. 11:29:11 [elastic-2] INFO  - onNext(A)  Flux.log(App.java:23)
11. Thread: elastic-2 , A
12. 11:29:11 [elastic-2] INFO  - | request(1)   Flux.log(App.java:18)
13. 11:29:11 [main] INFO  - | onNext(c)     Flux.log(App.java:18)
14. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - onNext(B)  Flux.log(App.java:21)
15. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - onNext(B)  Flux.log(App.java:23)
16. Thread: elastic-3 , B
17. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - | request(1)   Flux.log(App.java:18)
18. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - | onNext(d)    Flux.log(App.java:18)
19. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - | onComplete()     Flux.log(App.java:18)
20. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - onNext(C)  Flux.log(App.java:21)
21. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - onNext(C)  Flux.log(App.java:23)
22. Thread: elastic-3 , C
23. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - cancel()   Flux.log(App.java:21)
24. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - onComplete()   Flux.log(App.java:23)
25. 11:29:11 [elastic-3] INFO  - | cancel()     Flux.log(App.java:18)
```

**Questions:** Each question is about a specific line inside the output (not a line in the code). I also added my answers to some of them but I'm not sure I'm correct.

4. When subscribing, the subscribe operation ask for `unbounded` amount of elements. Then why the event: `request(unbounded)` is going down in the pipeline instead of going up? My answer: The request for `unbounded` amount is going up to `take` and then `take` sending it down again.
5. `flatMap` send `cancel` signal. Why doesn't `take` sends it instead?

Last question: There is more then one terminal signal in the output. Isn't it a vaulation of reactive-streams spec?

Comment: Please ask a single question per question.

Comment: __They are all related to the same code & output__. Should I create 10 topics instead?

Comment: Yes you should, but not all at once. Ask a focussed question, do some research. The problem with asking 8 questions in one is that you likely don't get them all answered, there may already be a duplicates for some of them already. You make your question too broad, which will lead to closing, and you have given it a very poor title, which will lead to people ignoring it, or at least getting the right people to ignore it. If you ask a focussed question, most of those problems go away.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, will be produced ONLY one terminal signal.

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d")
            .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line: 18
            .flatMap(value ->
                    Mono.just(value.toUpperCase()).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()), 2)
            .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line: 21
            .take(3)
            .log(null, Level.INFO, true) // line: 23
            .subscribe(x ->
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
 " , " + x), t -> {}, () -> System.out.println("Completed ""Only Once"));
```

The tricky part here is that each Reactor 3 operator has its own life, and they all are playing by the same rule - emit `onComplete` to notify downstream operator that there is no data anymore.

Since you have `.log()` operator and three different points thus you will observe three independent `onComplete` signals from `.just`, from `.flatMap`, and from `.take(3)`.

Firstly, you will see `onComplete` from `.just` because the default behavior of `.flatMap` is 'ok, let's try to request first `concurrency` elements, and then let's see how it goes', since `.just` may produce (in your case) only 4 elements, on 2 (which is concurrency level in your example) requested demand it will emit 2 `onNext` and after two `request(1)` you will see `onComplete`. In turn, emitted `onComplete` lets the `.flatMap` knows that when 4 flatted streams emit their `.onComplete` signals, it will be allowed to emit its own `onComplete` to downstream. 
In turn, downstream is `.take(3)` operator which is also after first three elements will emit its own `onComplete` signal without waiting for upstream `onComplete`. Since there is `.log` operator after `.take` this signal also will be recorded.
Finally, in your flow, you have 3 independent log operators, which will record 3 independent `onComplete` from 3 independent operators, but despite that fact, the final terminal `.subscribe` will receive only one `onComplete` from the first operator up to the flow.

### Small update regarding `.take` behavior

The central idea of `.take` is taking elements until the remaining count has been satisfied. Since the upstream may produce more than was requested we need to have a mechanism to prevent sending more data. One of the mechanisms that Reactive-Streams spec offers to us is collaborations over `Subscription`. Subscription has two primary methods - `request` - to show the demand and `cancel` - to show that data is not needed anymore even if requested demand was not satisfied.
In case of `.take` operator, [initial demand](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxTake.java#L95) is `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which considers as unbounded demand. Therefore, the only way to stop consuming potentially infinitive stream of data is to [cancel](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxTake.java#L109) subscription, or in other word unsubscribe

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hi Oleh, as usual, thanks for the help! Can you please also write about the `cancel` signal: Why `take` is getting `cancel` signal? Also, if you can, please refer to my first question.

Comment: Hey, you are welcome :) updated, Also, sorry for confusion with 8 requested from flatMap. I missed your concurrency level which is 2

Comment: Why `take` asks for `Long.MAX_VALUE` instead of the value I specified?

Comment: I believe that mentioned thing was done with the thought of optimization. If you take a look at some simple operator like [`FluxArray`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxArray.java#L88), you will see that depends on initial requested demand will be chosen the particular emitting strategy, which in case of `Long.MAX_VALUE` will be much efficient than in case of small initial demand, which tries to cover more corner cases, etc